# Android - Too many open files error

Tags: android

I am getting `"Too many open files"` error on a android device.

Is it possible for me list all open files by my app in Emulator?

**Android lsof equivalent?**

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to emulator using **adb shell** command and then execute **lsof** command:

```
lsof | grep <PID>
```

where  is process of your app (can be found in Android Studio if connected via debug) or you can use your app package name instead of **PID** - this should also work